# disable syntax highlight on inactive windows

Tags: window, font-lock, syntax-highlighting

I got the following code for highlighting inactive and active windows with different background color.  How do I make so that inactive windows have no syntax highlighting, only the active window has?

```el
;; For inactive windows
(defun highlight-selected-window ()
  "Highlight selected window with a different background color."
  (walk-windows (lambda (w)
                  (unless (eq w (selected-window))
                    (with-current-buffer (window-buffer w)
                      (buffer-face-set '(:background "#262626")))))
                (font-lock-mode 0)
                )
  (buffer-face-set '(:background "#111"))
  (font-lock-mode 1)
  )
(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'highlight-selected-window)
```

As you can see, I tried to add the (font-lock-mode 0) to turn syntax off in the inactive windows. This turns off the syntax highlighting, however; the active window also has its syntax turned off.

Please let me know how to fix this and thank you

Comment: You just didn't put the `(font-lock-mode 0)` into the `unless`-form.

Comment: Note that switching `font-lock-mode` off and on just for selecting windows is quite expensive. Furthermore, if you display the same buffer in multiple windows. Your method does not work for those windows. I often have multiple windows for one and the same buffer to see different parts of the buffer simultaneously.